# Can exceeded CloudWatch limit fail the entire request: Rate exceeded (Service: CloudWatch, Status Code: 400)

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-cloudwatch, logback

There is a RESTful web service with endpoint /foo.
When a user invokes /foo underlying method:

1. does some useful stuff;
2. logs something into the CloudWatch;
3. returns a useful response body as a JSON object.

What happens when the service exceeds CloudWatch limits?

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatch.model.CloudWatchException: Rate exceeded (Service: CloudWatch, Status Code: 400
```

Do we just lose the logs and still the user gets desired response?
Or does the user gets 400 or 500 errors just because we exceeded the CloudWatch limits?
Can we do anything to prevent the failure of the main functionality?

Here is the dependency from pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudwatch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It's a SpringBoot application with standard Logback.

Comment: Sounds like you are manually trying to push logs into cloudwatch. Doing that yourself naively is a bad idea as shown here. Instead your log pushing should be handled by a process that is entirely detached from any user interaction, that process (micro)batches the logs, has retry behavior with backoff, etc. and cannot block any user request. If you are running in EC2 or ECS or Lambda or Batch there should be no need to do any manual log submission at all anyway. And obviously if you get an error and do not retry than you loose whatever request you tried.